# Maximum of a sequence of almost-identical independent normal random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Take a sequence $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ where each $X_i\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is an i.i.d. normal random variable.  Denote by $X_\max$ the maximum of this sequence.  A well-known fact about convergence of $X_\max$ is that $\frac{X_\max-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2\log n}}\rightarrow 1$ almost surely (for instance, see Example 4.4.1 in Galambos "The Asymptotic Theory of Extreme Order Statistics").

Now suppose you scale an arbitrary element $X_j$ of the sequence above by a small amount to get a new sequence: $X_1,\ldots,(1+\epsilon)X_j,\ldots,X_n$ where $\epsilon=o\left(\sqrt{\frac{\log n}{n}}\right)$.  Is there a convergence result for the maximum of this almost-identically distributed sequence of independent normal random variables?  It seems to that that almost-sure convergence similar to above should exist, but I am having hard time deriving it...

Comment: May I ask what the source of the question is? Is this homework or a stated result somewhere? I'd like to have an idea of whether there's a good chance that the stated convergence result does not hold for the augmented sequence.

Comment: I haven't checked the details, but I think $\frac{X_max - \mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2 \log n}}\to 1 \mbox{a.s.}$ still holds as long as $\epsilon=o(1)$. To prove this, show that for any $\delta>0$, $(1+\epsilon)X_j$ cannot exceed $\mu+(1+\delta)\sigma\sqrt{2\log n}$ infinitely many times. For this, use Borel-Cantelli and a standard tail bound for the normal distribution (e.g., see http://mikespivey.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/normaltails/). Again, I haven't checked this all goes through, but I suspect it does.

Comment: Thanks for comments! This isn't a homework, it came up in the course of research.  I think your approach is right, I was thinking along the same lines.  Also, looks like it's important that $\epsilon=o\left(\sqrt{\frac{\log n}{n}}\right)$ may be important, as otherwise one can't prove that $(1+\epsilon)X_i$ will never exceed the threshold (at least not using the standard inequalities).

Comment: You don't need to show that $(1+\epsilon)X_i$ never exceeds the threshold. (In fact, there's always a positive probability it will!) You just need to show that for each $\delta>0$, $\frac{(1+\epsilon)X_j - \mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2\log n}}$ does not exceed $1+\delta$ *infinitely often*. That's where Borel-Cantelli comes in. I'll write a more detailed answer later if you haven't solved it yet.

Comment: By "never exceed the threshold" I meant "in the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ the probability of exceeding the threshold is zero as opposed to a positive number" -- sorry for sloppiness. Let me see if I can figure out the application of the Borel-Cantelli lemma here...  will let you know.

Comment: Ok, call event $E_n$ $(1+\epsilon)X_i$ exceeding the threshold $\mu+(1+\delta)\sigma\sqrt{2\log n}$. Using the  Chernoff-type tail bounds for the standard normal variables, $P(E_n)\leq\exp\left[-\left(\frac{1+\delta}{1+\epsilon}\sqrt{2\log n}-\frac{\epsilon\mu}{(1+\epsilon)\sigma}\right)^2/2\right]$  We don't need the refined tail bounds, and we can throw away the term $\frac{\epsilon\mu}{(1+\epsilon)\sigma}$ from the exponential.  Thus the upper bound is $\approx n^{\left(-\frac{1+\delta}{1+\epsilon}\right)}$  (continued...)

Comment: Now, if $\epsilon=o(1)$, then for any fixed $\delta>0$, there will be a finite $N_0$ where $\epsilon<\delta$ for all $n>N_0$, which means that $\frac{1+\delta}{1+\epsilon}>1$. Write $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(E_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{N_0}P(E_n)+\sum_{n=N_0}^{\infty}P(E_n)$. The first sum is obviously finite.  The second sum is upper-bounded by the Reimann Zeta function with an argument which is greater than one, which is a finite number. Thus, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(E_n)<\infty$, and by Borel-Contelli lemma, the threshold isn't exceeded infinitely often. The claim follows.  So, did I do this correctly?  :)

Comment: Looks right to me. The sum is finite. Theorem proved. You might want to copy that to an answer below.